# TypeScript with Redux. Redux Saga How to wait for the LOAD_SUCCESS to return and save your data for later use

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm new to using redux and redux-saga.

I'm having trouble retrieving information for an object when an action is sent to the API.
When I use a log in "promocoesSagas" the first time it returns null, it only returns with the object after the LOAD_REQUEST is successful, which is obvious.
What approach should I take so that my application waits to receive this data?
Because if I invoke a

```
const promocoesItems = promocoesSagas.data.item;
```

the application is interrupted because the data has not yet been loaded because the "LOAD_REQUEST", returning null the first time.
[First time call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt072.png)
[Trying access the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVNF0.png)

**My useEffect hook:**

```
const List = () => {
...

const promocoesSagas = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.promocoes);   
console.log(promocoesSagas);
const promocoesItem = promocoesSagas.data.items;
console.log(promocoesItem);

const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<PromocoesActions>>();

 useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
     setIsloading(true);
     try {
       dispatch({ type: PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_REQUEST, payload: query });
     } catch (error) {
       const errorResult: ErrorResult = error;
       if (
         errorResult.result != null &&
         errorResult.result.statusCode === 403
       ) {
         push('/error-403');
         return;
       }
       message.error(errorResult.message);
     }
     setIsloading(false);
  })();
}, [query, refetch]);

   return (...)}
```

**actions.ts**

```
const loadPromocoesAsync = createAsyncAction(
 PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_REQUEST,
 PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS,
 PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_FAILURE,
)<PromocoesQuery, FetchResult<PromocoesModel>, undefined>();

 export { loadPromocoesAsync };
```

**reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE: PromocoesState = {
  data: null,
  error: false,
  loading: false,
};

const reducer: Reducer<PromocoesState> = (
  state = INITIAL_STATE,
  action: PromocoesActions,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: false, data: action.payload };
    case PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**sagas.ts**

```
function* load(action: ReturnType<typeof loadPromocoesAsync.request>) {
  try {
    const query = action.payload;
    const response: FetchResult<PromocoesModel> = yield call(
      api.getPromocoes,
      query,
    );
    yield put(loadPromocoesAsync.success(response));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(loadPromocoesAsync.failure());
  }
}

export { load };
```

**types.ts**

```
type PromocoesActions = ActionType<typeof promocoesActions>;

enum PromocoesActionTypes {
  LOAD_REQUEST = 'LOAD_REQUEST',
  LOAD_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_SUCCESS',
  LOAD_FAILURE = 'LOAD_FAILURE',
}

interface PromocoesState {
  readonly data: FetchResult<PromocoesModel> | null;
  readonly loading: boolean;
  readonly error: boolean;
}

export { PromocoesActions, PromocoesActionTypes, PromocoesState };
```

**root-reducer**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  promocoes,
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export default rootReducer;
```

**root-sagas**

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  return yield all([takeLatest(loadPromocoesAsync.request, load)]);
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to *use* `promocoesItem`...it seems you are just trying to access it in the function component body in a console.log?

Comment: Sorry if i could not add any necessary information.

After your comment, i saw that my other component was getting the wrong kind of return, and had just placed a console.log () before the information I was still loading was passed on to the other component.

Comment: So are you still trying to solve this, or is it solved?

Comment: is resolved, I was just adding what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost set, you just need to handle your redux variables in the react app, I'll advise to do something like this in the **List** component, remember that your promocoes reducer already has the loading or error variable:

```
// Here you grab the values from the store, you don't need any local state.
const {data, loading, error, } = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.promocoes);

const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<PromocoesActions>>();

// Your useEffect can be simplified, because your api call is already handled by the saga

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch({ type: PromocoesActionTypes.LOAD_REQUEST, payload: query });
}, [query, refetch]); 

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>

if (error) return message.error(errorResult.message)

// Assuming data is an array
return data && data.length > 0 && (
  // Your component
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

After Seth Lutske responded, I realized that my other component was getting the wrong data type. And I had just put a 'console.log ()' before LOAD_REQUEST did its job.

**What was before:**

```
    const List = () => {
    ...
    
    useEffect(()=>{...},[query, refetch]);

           return(
              <PromocoesTable
                currentPage={query.pagination.page}
                isLoading={isLoading}
                pageItems={promocoes != null ? promocoes.items : []}
                onChange={(evt) => setQuery({ ...query, ...evt })}
                totalItems={promocoes != null ? promocoes.totalItems : 0}
                initialPageSize={query.pagination.pageSize}
                onAction={onTableAction}
              />
        )
}
```

**it became:**

```
        const List = () => {
        ...
        
        useEffect(()=>{...},[query, refetch]);

    return(
        <PromocoesTable
            currentPage={query.pagination.page}
            isLoading={isLoading}
            pageItems={promocoesSagas.data != null ? promocoesSagas.data.items : []}
            onChange={(evt) => setQuery({ ...query, ...evt })}
            totalItems={
              promocoesSagas.data != null ? promocoesSagas.data.totalItems : 0
            }
            initialPageSize={query.pagination.pageSize}
            onAction={onTableAction}
          />
    )
}
```

Sorry if it was a very simple question and it was my mistake.
Next time I will try a rubber duck.